# VBS Runtime error 800A000D - Type mismatch

Tags: dynamic, vbscript, arrays

I am trying to run a .VBS script from Windows Explorer (IIS Manager 6) and am a novice VBScript programming. I am getting above error when running the following code.  What am I doing wrong?  I just need to generate the IIS MIME types please!

Error detail: Line 49, char 5;
where line 49:

```
MimeMapArray = MimeMapObj.GetEx("MimeMap")
```

Code fixed now.  Here is how it should look:

```
' This script adds the necessary Windows Presentation Foundation MIME types 
' to an IIS Server.
' To use this script, just double-click or execute it from a command line.
' Running this script multiple times results in multiple entries in the IIS MimeMap.
' Set the MIME types to be added
Dim MimeMapObj
Dim MimeMapArray()
Dim WshShell
Dim oExec
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2

Dim MimeTypesToAddArray
MimeTypesToAddArray = Array(".manifest", "application/manifest", ".xaml", _
    "application/xaml+xml", ".application", "application/x-ms-application", _
    ".deploy", "application/octet-stream", ".xbap", "application/x-ms-xbap", _
    ".xps", "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument")

' Get the mimemap object 
Set MimeMapObj = GetObject("IIS://LocalHost/MimeMap")

' Call AddMimeType for every pair of extension/MIME type
For counter = 0 to UBound(MimeTypesToAddArray) Step 2
    AddMimeType MimeTypesToAddArray(counter), MimeTypesToAddArray(counter+1)
Next

' Create a Shell object
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Stop and Start the IIS Service
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("net stop w3svc")
Do While oExec.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("net start w3svc")
Do While oExec.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Set oExec = Nothing

' Report status to user
WScript.Echo "Windows Presentation Foundation MIME types have been registered."

Dim i
' AddMimeType Sub
Sub AddMimeType(ByVal Ext, ByVal MType)

    ' Get the mappings from the MimeMap property. 
    ' Add a new mapping. 
    For i = 0 to 14
' UBound(MimeMapArray) - 1
    ReDim Preserve MimeMapArray(i)
    Set MimeMapArray(i) = CreateObject("MimeMap")
    MimeMapArray(i).Extension = Ext
    MimeMapArray(i).MimeType = MType
    MimeMapObj.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE, "MimeMap", MimeMapArray
    MimeMapObj.SetInfo()
Next

End Sub
```